# Handle large amount of server data

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds

I am using Flex 3, with BlazeDS to interact with Java layer and fatch the data. I am getting more then 10000 rows of data at a time to display in my datagrid. I am displaying it 200 at a time and using it paging for the application. (Whenever I call the next button link, a server call happen and fetch the next 200 data)

I was wondering is there any other technique we can use flex side to buffer the 10000 data and display everything without calling server everytime.

Thanks for your any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an intermediate layer in your Flex application which can hold all data in it, and then perform the paging on it.

1. Fetch all data
2. Store it in an ArrayCollection (or ArrayList, Array or other that
   suit your needs)
3. Create a method to retrieve wanted data from it, for example:

   ```
   retrieveData(offset:int, limit:int):ArrayCollection
   ```

   It should retrieve the data starting from **offset** and end at **offset + limit**.
4. Calling `retrieveData(500, 20);` should return the 20 items starting
   from position 500.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is is possible something like streaming, like a video ? Like we dont have to wait for all the data to come , we just keep updating the screen ?